# Runtime/dynamic singleton types

Tags: json, haskell, singleton-type

```
$(singletons [d|
data MarketType
  = WinDrawWin
  | OverUnder
  deriving (Show, Generic)
|]

type family MarketIndex (mt :: MarketType) :: * where
  MarketIndex 'OverUnder = Double
  MarketIndex mt = ()

data Market (mt :: MarketType) = Market
 { marketType  :: SMarketType mt -- ^ type of the market
 , marketIndex :: MarketIndex mt -- ^ index of the market
 }

price :: SMarketType mt -> MarketIndex mt -> Either String (Market mt)
price SWinDrawWin ()   = Right $ Market SWinDrawWin ()
price SOverUnder  hcap = Right $ Market SOverUnder hcap
price mt          mi   = Left  $ unwords [show (fromSing mt), show mi, "can't be priced"]
```

The above (simplified) code works well for static code where all the types are known up front, but I want to extend it to be able to handle more dynamic input. For instance, a JSON request being made to price up one particular market - `WinDrawWin` or `OverUnder`. It's easy for me to create a `ToJSON` instance of all the types above using `fromSing` and my `ToJSON` instance on `MarketType`, but I'm not sure of the best way (if there is one) of creating the relevant `FromJSON` instances.

Should I have code that looks like this (single instance across all types of kind `'MarketType`)

```
instance FromJSON (SMarketType mt) where
    parseJSON = undefined
```

or this (separate instances per singleton)

```
instance FromJSON (SMarketType WinDrawWin) where
    parseJSON = undefined
```

or should I use the `FromJSON` instances for the type `MarketType` and then do something to recover the singleton types I require in `price`?

I'm aware of `toSing` but I've had no joy trying to understand how to correctly use it if that is what I require.

Comment: Is your final goal to implement `FromJSON` for `Market`? You can do that without needing to parse `MarketType` tags, if the `MarketIndex` fields provide enough information to disambiguate the types.